# Create a menu in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, list, menu, html-lists

I apologize in advance for the dumb question but I only learned some basic html a few years back. I don't remember much of it.

I want to create a cheap menu with 2 buttons (images + hover) on top of a banner but they don't want to align horizontally and in the absolute center of the banner.

Like this one http://i.imgur.com/Kcff92Q.png.

I searched and examined sample websites but I can't figure this one out.

This is the html and the css.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Generic Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="bannerb">

<div id="buttoncenter">

    <div id="button1"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/homebout.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/homebin.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/homebout.gif'"></a></div>

    <div id="button2"><a href="page2.html"><img src="images/p2out.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/p2in.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/p2out.gif'"></a></div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#bannerb {
background:transparent url("images/bannerb.gif");
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:150px;
width:800px;
}

#buttoncenter {
width:800px;
height:50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#button1 {
width:200px;
height:50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#button2 {
width:200px;
height:50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: So? What do you want us to do about it? You haven't told us where the problem is.

Comment: #buttoncenter has 50px as height, and contains 2 elements that have 50px as height, which means half of its content will be hidden. EDIT: didn't see the float right... Why do you put that?

Comment: My bad, I edited the post for more clarity.

I am very unexperienced in html. I read about the list tags but I went with div blocks instead since it seemed easier. So far, it's doing alright but I can't align and center the red buttons properly.

I was looking for insights.

Comment: @Morder Here you go [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpo32kqt/3/), no image needed. Pure CSS. Enjoy. (If you didn't want it to look like that just set background images in each button)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:right;` from `button2` css definition and all should go well

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `ul` - an unordered list for creating a "menu"

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
```